# Foursquare's Android native oauth authorization flow produces blank Foursquare

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, native, foursquare

I am working on an app that connects to Foursquare via the Foursquare's native oauth for Android libraries. I have implemented the example that Foursquare suggests on their github profile:

https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth

The app seems to connect and authorize fine on my own personal device and on a couple more; however, in some testing devices after sending the auth intent to Foursquare's app, Foursquare does not load their auth form, instead it only shows its blue action bar and a blank screen with no content at all. Pressing back only cancels the intent and returns to my app with a cancel code.

I can't seem to find out what causes that the same code works for some devices and for others not. I have tried updating, reinstalling and connecting to strong Wi-Fi signal on all devices, but to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, what can I do to prevent this bug from happening?

Comment: Hi there -- thank you for bringing this to our attention. This isn't the first time we've heard about this kind of error, but we haven't been able to reliably reproduce this bug. Can you email us (api@foursquare.com) with as many examples as you have of this failing with details? (OS version, phone model, Foursquare version installed, user already logged in/out, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, will do, and will also update this question as we advise towards a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've taken a look into this and have determined there is an issue with how native auth works in non-English system languages. We're working on a fix and the issue will be addressed in the next build we release.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience!

Comment: Update: this issue was addressed in the 2013.11.27 Foursquare for Android release.